# onBackpressed on CordovaActivity not called

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-activity, cordovawebview

I want to override onBackPressed function at CordovaActivity.
I use SystemWebview from cordova over CordovaActivity, and I need to override back function than I can make my method to go back.

I was already use this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //my method backpressed
    onBackPressedConfirmation();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                //my method backpressed
                onBackPressedConfirmation();
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

And nothing works. I was give breakpoint and debugging into that method but not stopping at that method. So CordovaActivity have different way to call backpressed function?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

U can pass Intent try bellow code on BackPress

```js
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CordovaActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
```